# Detecting the faces which are viewed through a rectangle div

Tags: three.js

here i struggle to detect the faces which are viewed through the div. rectangle div is in 2D, model is in 3D space. can anyone give me some clear suggestion on the same.

[image: Face detection inside the rectangle div]

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: i achieved by converting vector3 coordinates to vector2 it makes more simple to complete the task. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

The following uses the camera to build a bounding frustum and then test for intersections.

```
var frustum = new THREE.Frustum();
frustum.setFromMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().multiply( camera.projectionMatrix, camera.matrixWorldInverse ) );

for (var i=0; i<objects.length; i++) {
    if (frustum.intersectsObject(objects[i])) {
        // intersects
    } else {
        // no intersection
    }
}
```